# Overload resolution chooses generic overload over more concrete signature

Tags: c#, generics, overloading

I am trying to achieve the same behavior has EF Core currently has in place, with their [`Include`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#eager-loading) methods.

Take the following example:

```cs
new Foo<int, string>().Bar();        // Prints: Foo with less concrete method signature.
new Foo<int, List<string>>().Bar();  // Prints: Foo with less concrete method signature.

public class Foo<TOne, TTwo> 
{

}

public static class FooExtensions
{
    public static void Bar<TOne, TTwo>(this Foo<TOne, IEnumerable<TTwo>> foo) where TTwo : class
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Foo with more concrete method signature.");
    }

    public static void Bar<TOne, TTwo>(this Foo<TOne, TTwo> foo) where TTwo : class
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Foo with less concrete method signature.");
    }
}
```

Problem here is, that it doesn't choose the first `Bar` overload, when the `Foo instance` specifies a class which inherits `IEnumerable` for `TTwo`.

However if we look at EF Core and their `Include`/`ThenInclude` method signatures:

```cs
public static IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, TProperty> ThenInclude<TEntity, TPreviousProperty, TProperty>(this IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, TPreviousProperty> source, Expression<Func<TPreviousProperty, TProperty>> navigationPropertyPath) where TEntity : class;
public static IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, TProperty> ThenInclude<TEntity, TPreviousProperty, TProperty>(this IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, IEnumerable<TPreviousProperty>> source, Expression<Func<TPreviousProperty, TProperty>> navigationPropertyPath) where TEntity : class;
```

And you would call it like this:

```cs
someContextInstance.SomeDataSet.Include(x => x.SomeEntity).ThenInclude(x => x.SomeCollection);
```

It will actually choose the right overload with the `IEnumerable` in the signature.

I do hope the question hasn't been asked yet, but I didn't really knew what to search for.

Comment: Note that if you do `new Foo<int, IEnumerable<string>>().Bar();` that it "works".  Basically a `Foo<int, List<string>>` is not a `Foo<int, IEnumerable<string>>`.  As for the `Includes` the first `Include` will return a `IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, IEnumerable<TPreviousProperty>>` and not a `IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, List<TPreviousProperty>>`

Comment: @juharr Ohh, I see whats happening there, thanks a lot. I am not sure how I _read over_ that.